# Dynamically creating and using a CSS module?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

I have styles being loaded from the server, and I have a few elements that I want to apply those loaded styles to with a class.  In example 1, it's because I need to use the css selectors.  In example 2, it's because the 3rd party component I'm using gets its active styles set through a class.

Note: I'm using ReactJS and CSS modules.

How do I dynamically create a CSS module class and apply it to a component?

Example 1

```
 renderSvg = () => {
    const { imageUrl, stylePreferences } = this.props
    const { primaryColor } = stylePreferences
    // using svg4everybody's polyfill to deal with CORS constraints
    // I'd want a css rule that would essentially apply
    // .svgClass path { fill: primaryColor }
    // would be great if I could dynamically create a css class and attach it to svg
    return (
      <svg fill={primaryColor}>
        <use xlinkHref={`${imageUrl}#Layer_1`} />
      </svg>
    )
  }
```

Example 2

```
const { stylePreferences } = this.props
const { borderTopColor } = stylePreferences
// stylePreferences are editable and saved/loaded from the server
// I'd like the active class to include these loaded styles
<ScrollLink
  onActiveClass={classes.foobar}
/>
```